# How to check how many users are visiting my sites

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know how many users go to my sites.

ex. I have 3 sites a News site (main), a classifieds site and a travel guide site.

I need to know how many users went to my news site then went to my classifieds site or user who went to classified site then went to my travel guide and so on

Can I do this on google analytics if yes how?

Many thanks

Comment: I was able to get this working but is it possible to do the following? ex. a user goes to my main site then leaves my site and goes to other site amazon yahoo etc. then he went to google and search for something clicks on it and that site luckily is also one of my site let's say the travel site can we know in analytics that the user has been in my main site as well as my travel site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can setup cross domain tracking:

> Set up cross domain tracking by modifying the tracking code To set up
>   cross domain tracking for multiple top-level domains, you need to
>   modify the Analytics tracking code on each domain. You should have a
>   basic knowledge of HTML and JavaScript or work with a developer to set
>   up cross domain tracking. The examples in this article use the
>   Universal Analytics tracking code snippet (analytics.js).
>
> Set up a property in your Analytics account. For cross domain
>   tracking, set up one property in your Analytics account. Use the same
>   tracking code snippet and tracking ID from that property for all of
>   your domains. You need to edit the tracking code snippet for cross
>   domain tracking to work. If you haven’t already included the snippet
>   on all your webpages, you might want copy and paste it into a text
>   editor before continuing with the instructions here. This way, you
>   only have to make the changes once before including the modified
>   snippet on all your webpages.
>
> Edit the tracking code for the primary domain. Find the create line in
>   the snippet. For a website called example-1.com, it looks like this:
>
> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'example-1.com'); Make the following
>   changes to the snippet (the changes you need to make are in bold red
>   text):
>
> ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
>   ga('require', 'linker');   ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com'] );
>   Remember to replace the example tracking ID (UA-XXXXXX-Y) with your
>   own tracking ID, and replace the example secondary domain
>   (example-2.com) with your own secondary domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you use Google Tag Manager, it allows you fairly easily without working on js code.
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en